# Get text of element which is inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am working on a project in which I have to load an `iframe` inside a HTML table and get the text that is written inside a `<h2>` tag of the iframe. I tried the following code:

```
var iframes = $('iframe').contents().find("html").html();
alert(iframes);
```

I also tried some other variations of it that I found, but it didn't work. You can refer this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YeWMbW) code.

Does someone know what am I doing wrong? All suggestions are openly welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: any errors?same origin?

Comment: No, not untill now

Comment: From viewing your Codepen I can see that the iframe source is on a different domain, so you cannot  amend the content. It would be a massive security flaw if it were possible.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you mean its not possible?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: alright, i'll see if there's something else that I can do